# Git copy changes from one branch to another without committing the changes in source branch

Tags: git

I am new to git. I have a branch named BranchA from the master. I have some changes in BranchA (I am not going to merge changes from BranchA to master). Now I have created another branch from the master named BranchB. I want the changes from BranchA to BranchB. Here, I don't want to commit the changes in BranchA. And changes in the BranchA(which are copied to BranchB) should get deleted.

Comment: Can you checkout the new branch?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the changes you have is uncommited and unstaged. Then you can use git stash:

```
git stash
```

Then move to your Branch B and then:

```
git stash apply
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include the new changes from BranchA to BranchB then first commit and push on Branch A but if you don't want to commit the changes then first discard the current changes.
Then switch to new branch usind `git checkout BranchB` 
then try pulling branch `git pull origin BranchA`